# Splitting a value in SQL cell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Hello all so I have a question regarding SQL.
In my database I have a table with 4 rows (key , value , help , description) in value i have a long name something like : `Howard Beach 15 678 Mill Grave ave p.o box`.
Is it possible to change this field so it can look like this :

```
Howard Beach 15
678 Mill Grave ave
p.o box
```

I'am not talking about using SELECT I would like to insert some line breaker or something into the database so this addres is displayed in html not in one line but compacted. Because now it reads it from the database as one big line.
Does SQL have any separators that i could write to the database to change this viewing ?

I have SQL Server 2016.

I tried manually change something in the value cell but SQL has no features like that. Would be great if "enter" worked but no luck.

Comment: Just add a newline (character 10)??

Comment: Not understanding your last paragraph - what did you "manually change"? What feature of SQL do you think you're missing? The only feature needed is the ability to update the value with the correct data, so you would insert a linefeed in the appropriate place. This won't of course work for displaying in a HTML document where you'll need to replace the linefeed characters with the appropriate markup ie <br/> etc. Of course ideally the data would have been entered correctly to start with.

Comment: Please use an update statement (e.g. `UPDATE dbo.tablename SET Address = 'Howard Beach 15' + char(13) + char(10) + '678 Mill...' WHERE AddressID = 15;`), and not some half-baked UI that tries to treat table data like a spreadsheet. Whatever takes this from SQL to HTML is going to have to replace char(10)+char(10) with `<br>`. And this is going to be manual, SQL Server isn't going to be able to guess where a cr/lf pair should go. It might make more sense to clean this data up at the source and re-import it.

Comment: mixing format information in stored data is not a good idea. what if you want to show the same value in another control, a printed report, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Whichever solution is best is depended of your specific application and data intake process, how much work it would take to implement the changes, what changes are going to save you the most work over time, what follows best practices, and keeps your data in the most meaningful, useful format.

A. The easiest solution, although this may not be best, is probably to use CSS styling to alter the appearance of the address text on the front-end. Normally if that that is the job of the front-end person/people. Placing the value inside a sized `div` would keep a really long address line from appearing on a page.

```css
.sizedDiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="sizedDiv">
<p class="valueP"> Address Recipient, Address Line 1, Address Line 2, etc.</p>
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

B. Another possible solution would be changing the way values are stored in the db, by dividing values up into different parts (Value_Line_1, Value_Line_2, etc.) in the table, and then pulling out those fields and joining them as needed on the front-end. Of course depending on how the application is constructed, this may take some work depending on how values are imported, especially is data is imported from an external source and you have no control over the intake process for new addresses.

C. Adding a char(10), or any other character, and then splitting on the front-end, which is the direction the conversation above seemed to be leading, is a solution that would introduce a possibility for errors, in the case where that character appears unexpectedly elsewhere in the address text.

D. It is also possible to divide up value strings arbitrarily based on a specific character length, here's an example in SQL Server format:

```
DECLARE @addressLength INT = 25;
SELECT SUBSTRING([value], 1,  (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength))))  ) AS line_1,
SUBSTRING([value], (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength)))) + 1, 
(@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength)))), @addressLength))))
) AS line_2,
SUBSTRING([value], @addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength))) + (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength)))), @addressLength)))) + 1, 30 )  AS line_3
From Value_Table_Here;
```

this could be used to divide up values into parts in your table, although this solution would not divide up data in a meaningful pieces (i.e. Address Line 1, Address Line 2, etc.) You could save these address/value parts in a view that can be delivered to the application.

E. An alternate method of this would be using a similar query to above to just inserting `<br/>` elements at certain points in the address/value string:

```
DECLARE @addressLength INT = 25;
SELECT SUBSTRING([value], 1,  (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength))))  ) +'<br/>'+
SUBSTRING([value], (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength)))) + 1, 
(@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength)))), @addressLength))))
) +'<br/>'+
SUBSTRING([value], @addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength))) + (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], (@addressLength - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING([value], 1, @addressLength)))), @addressLength)))) + 1, 30 )  AS formattedAddress
From Value_Table_Here;
```

the formatted address or values could be saved in a view and delivered to the application as well.

Comment: Thanks for great support on the subject at hand this is my code : 

  **<td style="text-align: left;" class="Sender">
                    <span>{{Sender}}</span>**

The "Sender" is collecting data from the database and printing it on html in single line. Because it pulls out different addreses from the database it has to be in this format is it possible to apply changes to it that you where talking about ?

Comment: you could try to do css styling on your tables like the example from this article: [link](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-wrap-the-content-of-a-table-cell.html) or you could try something like `<td style="text-align: left; display: inline-block; width: 200px;" class="Sender"> <span>{{Sender}}</span>`